# HTML-Import in Confluence: background-color in inline style lost

Tags: css, background-color, confluence

I have a script that generates the HTML code like:

```html
<div style="background-color:#99ffff9c;border:1.0px solid #3296fa;border-radius:1.5em;width:1.5em;height:1.5em;display:inline-block;text-align:center">
  T
</div>
```

and imports it into Confluence.

The div tag on resulting page looks like so:
[image: screen]
, so that the `background-color` is lost.

Any way to force Confluence import the BG-color properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a workaround, maybe it will help someone...

I'm simulating the background of the circle with a UNICODE character ⬤

```html
<div style="border: 2.0px solid rgb(50,150,250);border-radius: 24.0px;width: 24.0px;height: 24.0px;display: inline-block;font-size: 24.0px;line-height: 21.0px;text-align: center;color: rgb(50,150,250);">⬤</div>
```

and is imported like charm [image]